# Generating token for client not working - Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: c#, .net, bearer-token, microsoft-identity-platform

I am trying to generate a JWT token for client. I have below code

```
var clinetid = "xxxxxxxx-b98c-4bd4-a3d7-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
var clientSecret = "UxpoxboRY0t-xxxxx~jF5~DFxxxx_xxxxx";
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clinetid)
                                                          .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)

                                                          .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                                                          .Build();

 string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://xxxxxxxx-b98c-4bd4-a3d7-xxxxxxxxxxxx/.default" };

 AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

I am running this code from Windows from application -> class library project (.net framework 4.6.1) but this never get executed. I am using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.43.1  Is there anything I am missing here if anyone can direct me

Comment: what happens when you set breakpoint at `AcquireTokenForClient` and debug? notice the Microsoft Identity [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop), always it will have try...catch block, and persist to cache.

Comment: yes, I have try catch block around, it not throwing exception. I debug line by line, once it hit AcquireTokenForClient it never come back

Comment: Follow one of the [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/activedirectory?view=azure-dotnet) and understand the flow, then you would be able to detect what is missing in your scenario.

Comment: I think that is Obsolete now

Comment: Have you checked this MSAL.NET [page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens) and the FAQ therein..?

Comment: Have you checked this MSAL.NET [page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens) and the FAQ therein..?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as your scope.